# How do I remove specific characters from a user-input?

Tags: python, user-input

I have a code which requires user input to function, however after testing it I would like to make it idiot proof. To do this I need to have it scrub out invalid characters in the is case anything besides numbers.

Comment: The question is incomplete. Please provide the code you are trying to. Stick to community guidelines when asking a question. [How to ask questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly you are trying to do.

Here are a few options:

## Check for specific values

**Option 1:** You can check for specific values using a list

```
test_input = input('Do you want to continue [y/n] : ')
valid = ['y','yes','n','no']
if test_input.lower() not in valid:
    print ('not a valid input')
else:
    print ('valid input')
```

**Option 2:** You can also iterate through a list and check for them

```
if any(test_input.lower() == i for i in valid):
    print ('valid input')
else:
    print ('not a valid input')
```

Output for the above two options are:

```
Do you want to continue [y/n] : good
not a valid input

Do you want to continue [y/n] : Good
not a valid input

Do you want to continue [y/n] : yes
valid input

Do you want to continue [y/n] : No
valid input
```

## Check using regex and replace using re.sub

If you want only numbers and alphabets (alphanumeric) values, you can check for them and replace everything else. For numbers and alphabets only, use `'[^0-9a-zA-Z]+'`, if you want to add space as well, use `'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+'`. After `Z`, I added a space. You can include whatever you want inside the `[]`.

```
import re
user_input = input('Enter only alphabets and numbers : ')
cleansed_input = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', user_input)
print (cleansed_input)


Enter only alphabets and numbers : 42 days into Stardom!!! is Gr#aT
42daysintoStardomisGraT

Enter only alphabets and numbers : 42 days #Star!!!()32*%53
42 days Star3253
```

First one excludes space, second one includes space.

Answer (score 0):

use any() | it's a built in function

Comment: care to explain this a bit more. You are on the right track but OP may need more clarity on what you mean

Comment: he did not provide any base code for what was seemingly a simple program, so i feel like he did not care to learn anything, but instead wanted to just copy/paste

Comment: That is not how our community works. We provide quality answers and encourage OPs to improve their questions. Please review how you answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do is probably using `string.translate`

```py
CHARS_TO_REMOVE = " ?!;:,."
trans = "".maketrans({ i:"" for i in CHARS_TO_REMOVE })
input_string = input()
sanitised_string = input_string.translate(trans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python regular expressions are great for this kind of job. To use regular expressions in python you need to import re module.

```
import re

x= "aiosdhasiujhd 123 12390123 123 -873 sd/. "

print(re.findall(r'-?\d+',x))
```

Output:

['123', '12390123', '123', '-873']

The aforementioned regular expression looks for a string with - at the start, repeated 0 or 1 times (? operator), followed by any number any number of times (\d+)